# React Native, how would i go about calling a function inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, react-native

So basically this is i what i want to do. I have a button which calls the handleAdd event, when that event triggers i want to call the useEffect function. The useEffect(); calls a function which returns a different api key depending on the value in input. But i have realized useEffect doesen't work that way and can only be called in the "top level" of the code. Is there some way i can work around this issue? See  example below:

```
 input = "example";  

  const handleAdd = () => {
    //Call useEffect
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCoinMarketDataApi.request("example");
  }, []);
```

Thanks in advance:) any input is appreciated, i'm having quite the hard time trying to figure out how to work with useEffect and async events so the answer might be obvious.

Comment: Why do you want to call it from within `useEffect`? Why not just call `getCoinMarketDataApi.request` from within `handleAdd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like the function that you have in `useEffect` should really be part of the function that gets passed to the `<button>`s `onClick` handler.

There are use cases when you do need to retrigger a `useEffect` in response to a button click (e.g. a project I’m working on needs to fetch data from a web service when the component is mounted and again if user input changes a value from the default) so:

`useEffect` functions get called when:

- The component is initially mounted
- When a dependency changes

So you can do what you are asking for by:

- Creating a state with `useState`
- Passing the state variable as a dependency to `useEffect`
- Setting that state variable in your click event handler